# How to set template to new python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, new-project

is there way to make "code template" in visual studio code?

All I want after creating new file is to fill the file with this code here like c# does...

This can save me time

```
# Imports
x = 10
# Set Variables

def main(text, number, variable):
    print("Hello, world..", text, number, variable)

# Main function


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("xyz", 5, x)
```

Comment: You could create a snippet, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no option to do this in IDLE. You will have to type it in manually.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to open a file with a code already written on it.
For that purpose you can use the following code:

```
f = open("myfile.py", "w") # This will create a file.
f.write('''
    # Imports
    x = 10
    # Set Variables

    def main(text, number, variable):
        print("Hello, world..", text, number, variable)

    # Main function


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main("xyz", 5, x)
    ''')
f.close()
```